# Include_once failed to open stream

Tags: php, mysql

I've been studying the issue for a while, can't find an answer.

Working on a PHP/mySQL project on XAMPP. The simplified structure is as follows:

```
--admin.php
--views 
  --admin
    --editor-html.php (includes the editor form)
--controllers
  --admin
    --editor.php (includes form processing)
```

**Code for editor.php:**

```
   <?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  var_dump($_POST);
}
//or this instead
// $buttonClicked = isset ($_POST['action']);
// if ($buttonClicked) {
//   $buttonType = $_POST ['action'];
//   $getData = ($buttonType === "save");
//   if ($getData) {
//     var_dump($_POST);
//   }
// }
$editorOutput = include_once "views/admin/editor-html.php";
return $editorOutput;
 ?>
```

The form's action="controllers/admin/editor.php".
At first when I open admin.php the editor form is showing. **When the form is submitted**, I get the `$_POST` data from the editor form printed, but the `include_once "views/admin/editor-html.php"` throws a "failed to open stream" error (despite the fact that before submitting the editor form was showing fine).

If I replace the `$_POST` handling from `controllers/admin/editor.php` to `admin.php`, and point form's action="admin.php", everything works fine.
Please let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1.) In the file structure you describe above, the filepath from `editor.php` to `editor-html.php` should be `../../views/admin/editor-html.php`

2.) Also, this...

```
$editorOutput = include_once "views/admin/editor-html.php";
return $editorOutput;
```

... IMO is too much. Just use this instead:

```
include_once "../../views/admin/editor-html.php";
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If that would be the case, then I would not get the editor form showing in the first place, before I submit the editor form.

Comment: $navClicked = isset ($_GET ['page']);
if ($navClicked) {
  $link = $_GET['page'];
} else {
  $link = "entries";
}
$pageData->content .= include_once "controllers/admin/$link.php";